Solve gives incomplete answer over complex numbers
I am running Mathematica 14.0.0.0 for desktop, on Windows.
Solve[Abs[x + y] == 20 && Abs[x^2 + y^2] == 16, {x, y}, Complexes]
yields
{{x -> 2 (-5 + 3 I Sqrt[3]), 
  y -> 2 (-5 - 3 I Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 2 (5 + 3 I Sqrt[3]), 
  y -> 2 (5 - 3 I Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 2 (-5 - 3 I Sqrt[3]), 
  y -> 2 (-5 + 3 I Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 2 (5 - 3 I Sqrt[3]), 
  y -> 2 (5 + 3 I Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 2 (-5 + I Sqrt[23]), 
  y -> 2 (-5 - I Sqrt[23])}, {x -> 2 (5 + I Sqrt[23]), 
  y -> 2 (5 - I Sqrt[23])}, {x -> 2 (-5 - I Sqrt[23]), 
  y -> 2 (-5 + I Sqrt[23])}, {x -> 2 (5 - I Sqrt[23]), 
  y -> 2 (5 + I Sqrt[23])}}

which is a finite list of solutions. However, this system of equations actually has infinitely many solutions: given any nonzero solution $(x,y)$, the pair $(e^{it} x, e^{it} y)$ is also a solution for any real number $t$. What gives?
Inspired by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4897393/19006

Solve can't return an infinite number of solutions, because it has to return a list of exact solutions. What exactly were you expecting? You could try to use Reduce instead, but I've tried it, and it seems to be taking a long time to run.

I suppose I was expecting at least a warning that this may not be a complete list of solutions. In more complicated examples, it may not be as obvious that the system you want to solve actually has infinitely many solutions and mathematica is only returning finitely many of them! Another question is: why is this particular set of solutions the one we get from Solve? It seems important for users to be able to interpret the result of a call to Solve; which I thought I could until today :)

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = Abs[x + y] == 20 && Abs[x^2 + y^2] == 16;

sol1 = Solve[eqn, {x, y}]

(* {{x -> 2 (-5 + 3 I Sqrt[3]), 
  y -> 2 (-5 - 3 I Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 2 (5 + 3 I Sqrt[3]), 
  y -> 2 (5 - 3 I Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 2 (-5 - 3 I Sqrt[3]), 
  y -> 2 (-5 + 3 I Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 2 (5 - 3 I Sqrt[3]), 
  y -> 2 (5 + 3 I Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 2 (-5 + I Sqrt[23]), 
  y -> 2 (-5 - I Sqrt[23])}, {x -> 2 (5 + I Sqrt[23]), 
  y -> 2 (5 - I Sqrt[23])}, {x -> 2 (-5 - I Sqrt[23]), 
  y -> 2 (-5 + I Sqrt[23])}, {x -> 2 (5 - I Sqrt[23]), 
  y -> 2 (5 + I Sqrt[23])}} *)

And @@ (eqn /. sol1)

(* True *)

Your offered result
sol2 = Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ (Values[sol1] E^(I*t))

(* {{x -> 2 (-5 + 3 I Sqrt[3]) E^(I t), 
  y -> 2 (-5 - 3 I Sqrt[3]) E^(I t)}, {x -> 2 (5 + 3 I Sqrt[3]) E^(I t), 
  y -> 2 (5 - 3 I Sqrt[3]) E^(I t)}, {x -> 2 (-5 - 3 I Sqrt[3]) E^(I t), 
  y -> 2 (-5 + 3 I Sqrt[3]) E^(I t)}, {x -> 2 (5 - 3 I Sqrt[3]) E^(I t), 
  y -> 2 (5 + 3 I Sqrt[3]) E^(I t)}, {x -> 2 (-5 + I Sqrt[23]) E^(I t), 
  y -> 2 (-5 - I Sqrt[23]) E^(I t)}, {x -> 2 (5 + I Sqrt[23]) E^(I t), 
  y -> 2 (5 - I Sqrt[23]) E^(I t)}, {x -> 2 (-5 - I Sqrt[23]) E^(I t), 
  y -> 2 (-5 + I Sqrt[23]) E^(I t)}, {x -> 2 (5 - I Sqrt[23]) E^(I t), 
  y -> 2 (5 + I Sqrt[23]) E^(I t)}} *)

And @@ Assuming[t ∈ Reals, eqn /. sol2 // Simplify]

(* True *)

The documentation states, "Solve deals  primarily  with  linear  and  polynomial  equations " and "Solve gives generic solutions only"
To get the complete solution you would need to evaluate either
Solve[eqn, {x, y}, Method -> Reduce]

or
Reduce[eqn, {x, y}]

However, neither evaluates within a time for which I'm willing to wait. Assuming that both will time out, then Mathematica cannot provide the full solution.

I don't understand how "Solve gives generic solutions only" is relevant here. In the documentation, this seems to be talking about discarding solutions which are only valid for some choices of continuous parameters.

Thank you for your response though. I am aware of Reduce and did also notice that it doesn't terminate in reasonable time in this case. I was just surprised at this result, because this is the first time I've seen a call to Solve give an incomplete solution with no warning or error message.

After an equivalent transform of eqn
eqn1 = ComplexExpand[ Abs[x + y]^2 == 20^2 && Abs[x^2 + y^2]^2 == 16^2 
/. {x -> a + I*b, y -> c + I*d}]

the Solve command of 14.0 on Windows 10 produces an infinite set of solutions in short time
Solve[eqn1, {a, b, c, d}, Reals]

which takes 40.3 MB in memory and
Reduce[eqn1, {a, b, c, d}, Reals]

produces the result which takes 4.3 MB in memory. Both results are useless. All that is art for art's sake.
